# what snake is this and is it venomous?

Tags: species-identification, zoology

Found on my house on Khao Yai, Thailand[image][image]

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a common wolf snake, or house snake (*[Lycodon capucinus](http://www.sjonhauser.nl/lycodon.html)*). Here another [picture](https://bangkokherps.files.wordpress.com/2011/05/house-snake-nick-baker.jpg). I think they are not dangerous, but be sure to take precautions (I might have guessed wrong from just your photos).

Comment: I'm not sure about that; it seems too blue, and it looks like the rear of the head on this one is wider.

Comment: what could it be then?

Comment: It's a _Lycodon_ for sure. One of the characters that helps when differentiating from other similar snakes is that the head is quite prominently separated from the neck. Also the nape band is quite common in many, but not all, _Lycodon sp_. I can't comment on whether it's indeed _L. capucinus_ or another _Lycodon_ species though.